# SQL Query - are functions injected in a query will be evaluated by Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if the SQL functions `extractvalue()` and `xmltype()` have chances to be executed in the following query or if they will be evaluated as a string value by the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (FIELD_1 IN ('foo','bar''||(select extractvalue(xmltype(''%gxgol;]>''),''/l'') from dual)||'''))
```

This query does not raise any error in Oracle and the output only contains the rows where `FIELD_1` equal `'foo'`.

Comment: Not if they are in quoted strings. I suspect you have some unintended single quotes there.

Comment: All those single quotes make it difficult to understand when the string start and end, that's why I am confuse. As it is, `'bar''.... from dual)||'''` will be evaluated as a single string?

Comment: If the single quotes are getting a bit unruly I suggest using the alternative string quoting mechanism, e.g  q'[This isn't a " symbol but is '''']'. This way everything between the brackets is output as-is - you don't need to quote the quoted quotes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the content of a string literal will not be executed. Thankfully.

You need a real subquery. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE FIELD_1 IN (
    SELECT 'foo' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bar' || extractvalue(bla,bla) FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation

Answer (score 1):

If you call them via

> execute immediate

, yes they will taken as functions.

for more info https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm